# Firefox extension installation priority

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

could you help me with quite rare situation. So I have Firefox extension installed via adding XPI into FF browser with some ID and than I have installed extension with the same ID but via Windows registry. Currently previous installation  (via adding XPI to browser manually) is preserved. It is fine, but the question is: is it possible that FF guys in some times will change this priority? Maybe exists some way to control that priority or perform any kind of overriding?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is no, never - extensions have unique ids, and you'll see they correspond to uniquely named folders in the extensions folder of your profile. It is impossible to create two folders with the same name in the same directory, and it doesn't make sense to have two versions of extension installed.

If you want to install a modified version as well, you could change the id and name in the install.rdf - see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Install_Manifests